# smbget gives always "File exists"

Tags: command-line, samba, smb

I am trying to use `smbget` to fetch a file from a Windows share from the command line, and whatever I try, I get the same (useless) error message:

```
[bf@localhost syntess]$ smbget -U username%password smb://SERVER/data/test.txt
Using workgroup SAMBA, user username
smbc_open: File exists
```

Whatever I try on the filename or user, I get the same error.

We all know Samba is notoriously bad at error messages, but this one takes the cake...

Answer (score 2):

Turned out the share name was invalid.